# R: Making Bigger Graphs when using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, plot, knitr

I'm having some trouble visualizing some data in an R Markdown document.  I'm attaching a picture for your reference.

I would like the graphs produced to be larger, and would expect the HTML page to allow for these graphs to be spread out, but they are all coming back "squished"

```
g <- ggplot(item_loc_metrics, aes(capc_ssp_ratio, avg_wk_bkrm_eoh)) + geom_point(color="firebrick")
g
```

I run this and it returns a nicely formatted graph:
[image: Graph of All data]

This snippet of code works fine, but I would like to cut this same graph 60+ times based on the store I'm looking at.  I've tried to to do that with this bit:

```
g2 <- ggplot(item_loc_metrics, aes(capc_ssp_ratio, avg_wk_bkrm_eoh)) + geom_point(color="firebrick") + facet_wrap(~CO_LOC_N, ncol=5, scales = "fixed", shrink = FALSE)
g2
```

I end up then getting something that looks like this:

[image: Graphs of data by store]

Comment: Increase `fig.height` and `fig.width` in the chunk options. For example, `\`\`\`{r fig.height=10, fig.width=12}`.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with your ggplot code, only with your chunk options.

Comment: Thanks very much! @eipi10

Answer (score 2):

To let this question have an answer, I add my two cents.

You can increase `fig.height` and `fig.width`(as suggested in the comment) and set `ncol` to one.